# System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку. В чём проблема?

Tags: c#, .net-framework

```
    ************** Текст исключения **************
System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Имя файла: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Имя файла: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral'
```

Несколько раз подчистую удалял все библиотеки и устанавливал заново через NuGet - не помогает. .NET Framework 4.8.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

```
<Reference Include="ClosedXML, Version=0.102.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ClosedXML.0.102.2\lib\netstandard2.0\ClosedXML.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.16.0\lib\net46\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ExcelNumberFormat, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23c6f5d73be07eca, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ExcelNumberFormat.1.1.0\lib\net20\ExcelNumberFormat.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Irony, Version=1.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ca48ace7223ead47, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Irony.NetCore.1.0.11\lib\net461\Irony.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="SixLabors.Fonts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d998eea7b14cab13, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\SixLabors.Fonts.1.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\SixLabors.Fonts.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

Comment: Конфликт версий какой-то. Значит не подчистую удаляли. Удалите пакет, проверьте референсы на сборки, удалите лишние. Затем установите пакет заново. Ну или показывайте csproj файл, где ссылки на сборки указаны. `Version=2.16.0.0` вот этого не должно быть.

Comment: @aepot Удалял через Get-Package | Uninstall-Package -RemoveDependencies -Force, он подчистую удаляет, вроде как. Тег Reference из csproj добавил в вопрос. Я так понял он ссылается на версию 3.0.0.0, когда зависимость у библиотеки от 2.16.0.0. Не знаю, как это исправить.

Comment: @aepot Помогло удаление из app.config всех зависимостей. После этого по новой накатил библиотеки и теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло следующее:

1. Удалил все пакеты с помощью `Get-Package | Uninstall-Package -RemoveDependencies -Force`
2. Удалил из `app.config` тег `<runtime></runtime>` целиком.
3. По новой установил библиотеки через NuGet.

Comment: Достаточно было удалить только конфликтную зависимость.